# How to select coordinates from GeoJSON via jQuery-UI autocomplete?

Tags: javascript, jquery-ui, autocomplete, geocoding, geojson

I am trying to create a simple geocoder, a service that turns names or addresses into coordinates.
I've got a simple GeoJSON-file, by the likes of this:

```
{"type": "FeatureCollection", "crs": { "type": "name", "properties": { "name": "urn:ogc:def:crs:OGC:1.3:CRS84" } },

"features": [
{ "type": "Feature", "properties": { "Name": "GOLM, HAUS 25, INSTITUT FÜR BIOCHEMIE UND CHEMIE", "Art": "universität" }, "geometry": { "type": "Point", "coordinates": [ 12.97433, 52.410289 ] } },
{ "type": "Feature", "properties": { "Name": "GOLM, HAUS 25, INSTITUT FÜR BIOLOGIE", "Art": "universität" }, "geometry": { "type": "Point", "coordinates": [ 12.97433, 52.410289 ] } },
//cont...
]
}
```

The whole file can be found [here](http://www.de-egge.de/maps/praesi/standorte.geojson).
I am using jQuery-UI to provide an input form with autocomplete, but it should only search each feature's name, i.e. when I type 'Golm' it would present every feature that has 'Golm' in its name.

After a name from the dropdown list is selected by the user, the features coordinates should be selected as a variable to put them on a map.

Can anyone provide a starting point? So far I've found out, that I can use a JSON-file as a source for the .autocomplete function, i.e.:

```
    $('#tags').autocomplete({
        source: 'standorte.geojson',
        minLength: 1,
        dataType: 'json'
    });
```

I would appreciate any help. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Have you [checked the documentation](http://api.jqueryui.com/autocomplete/#option-source)? You either need to create a server-side handler for a GET request or use a `source: function(request, response)` to fetch the whole file and filter it client-side

Answer (score 0):

My GeoJson structure looks like this:

```
{
"type":"FeatureCollection",
"features":[
    {"type":"feature",
        "geometry":{
        "type":"Point",
        "coordinates":[-1.8988,52.4776]
    },
    "properties":{
        "name":"Birmingham New Street Railway Station (BHM)",
        "category":"Train Station",
        "count":2}
    },
    {"type":"feature",
    "geometry":{
        "type":"Point",
        "coordinates":[-1.7337,52.4528]
    },
    "properties":{
        "name":"Birmingham Airport (BHX)",
        "category":"Airport",
        "count":2}
    },
    {"type":"feature",
    "geometry":{
        "type":"Point",
        "coordinates":[-1.7253,52.4507]
    },
    "properties":{
        "name":"Birmingham International Railway Station (BHI)",
        "category":"Train Station",
    "count":2}
}]}
```

And with this javascript the the value of the element with id `element_id_autosuggest_geosjon` is set. This can be extended for all of your objects from the GeoJson source.

```
$("#element_id_autosuggest_geosjon").autocomplete({
    source: function( request, response ) {
        $.ajax({
            url: '/path/to/json',
            dataType: 'json',
            data: { term: request.term },
            success: function( data ) {
                response($.map( data.features, function(item) {
                    return {
                        // match the objects to variables here
                        // do this for all of your objects
                        label: item.properties.name,
                        lon: item.geometry.coordinates[0],
                        lat: item.geometry.coordinates[1],
                        category: item.properties.category
                    };
                }));
            }
        });
    },
    select: function(event, ui) {
        // loop through the objects
        $.each(ui, function(key, element) {
            // set the value of the element with the variable
            $("#element_id_autosuggest_geosjon").val(element.label);
            $("#category").val(element.category);
            $("#location_geo_lon").val(element.lon);
            $("#location_geo_lat").val(element.lat);
        });
    }
});
```

You could use http://jquerygeo.com for your mapping.